# show tabular data in ul

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have below mentioned structure:

```css
* {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul{
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  width: 320px;
  position: absolute;
  background: #1f7f5c;
  color: #fff;
  max-height: 200px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

li {
  height: 50px;
  padding: : 12px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #2a8664;
  /*display: table-row !important;*/
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

.parent {
  padding-left: 21px;
  font-size: 22px;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><span class="parent"><span class="child">1</span><span>ABC1</span></span></li>
  <li><span class="parent"><span class="child">2</span><span>ABC2</span></span></li>
  <li><span class="parent"><span class="child">3</span><span>ABC3</span></span></li>
  <li><span class="parent"><span class="child">4</span><span>ABC4</span></span></li>
  <li><span class="parent"><span class="child">5</span><span>ABC5</span></span></li>
  <li><span class="parent"><span class="child">6</span><span>ABC6</span></span></li>
  <li><span class="parent"><span class="child">7</span><span>ABC7</span></span></li>
  <li><span class="parent"><span class="child">8</span><span>ABC8</span></span></li>
  <li><span class="parent"><span class="child">9</span><span>ABC9</span></span></li>
  <li><span class="parent"><span class="child">10</span><span>ABC10</span></span></li>
  <li><span class="parent"><span class="child">11</span><span>ABC11</span></span></li>
  <li><span class="parent"><span class="child">12</span><span>ABC12</span></span></li>
</ul>
```

### Notes:

Now, I want to keep the structure as it is. I mean no changes are allowed in html even using javascript or jquery. In short the rendered html should look as its mentioned and you cannot change it.

### Requirements:

I want to show data in columns.

### jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/Vishal1419/0bjvL00t/

**Update:**

[image]

Comment: Do you want to show the same as columns?

Comment: @HiteshMisro Yes I want to show as columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.parent {
padding-left: 21px;
font-size: 22px;
display: table;
vertical-align: middle;
height: 49px;
}
span.parent span {
display: table-cell;
border: 1px solid;
vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Add this

Comment: its very near to what I want but not exact. Please scroll down to the output. You  will see that there are no td differs.

Comment: hey add width in  % to the child span then you get equal width

Comment: Can you please give an example?

Comment: I have tried to implement as you said. But I am not getting the expected result. Can you please see image in my question.

Comment: [Click Here](https://jsfiddle.net/praveen_04/vux67mqh/4/) i updated by adding width

Comment: I have checked your fiddle. But one more problem. Please check this link: https://jsfiddle.net/Vishal1419/vux67mqh/5/ I have just changed the text in span

Comment: yeap i saw your fiddle and cleared it [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/praveen_04/vux67mqh/6/)

Comment: Thank you. That is most perfect.

Answer (score 1):

try restricting the height of the list so that the data automatically flows in to the column
In your ul give
 `<ul id="fixColumnHeight">`

`#fixColumnHeight{
    height: 300px;
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
       -moz-column-count: 3;
            column-count: 3; 
}`
`#fixColumnHeightli {
    display: inline-block; 
}`